# How to forcefully remove v4l2loopback kernel module?

Tags: 20.04, kernel, v4l

I am using [`ipwebcam-gst`](https://github.com/bluezio/ipwebcam-gst) to use my phone as a webcam. Sometimes, it does not correctly close the `v4l2loopback` module (e.g. when the phone was accidentally disconnected), and when I try to remove the module manually, I get an error.

```
$ sudo modprobe -r v4l2loopback
modprobe: FATAL: Module v4l2loopback is in use.
```

Without manually removing the module, ipwebcam won't work, and
I would have to restart my computer to get ipwebcam working once again.

How to forcefully remove the kernel module when the computer thinks that it is in use, but actually it is not doing anything?

If it can be removed with a command, then I won't have to restart the computer.
I also tried `$ sudo modprobe -rf v4l2loopback`, but it showed the same error.

Also, the output of `lsmod | grep v4l2loopback` is,

```
v4l2loopback           40960  1
videodev              225280  5 videobuf2_v4l2,v4l2loopback,uvcvideo,videobuf2_common
```

Comment: Please note that my question is about removing the kernel module, and not about ipwebcam-gst.

Comment: What version of Ubuntu?

Comment: There may be other modules preventing the removal. Try `lsmod | grep v4l2loopback` to list any modules that might be using `v4l2loopback`, and temporarily disable them. From there you may be able to remove `v4l2loopback`, but be ready to see `FATAL: Module v4l2loopback is builtin` if it’s an integral module.

Comment: @David I have tagged 20.04, and also this issue should not be version specific.